# Laravel 5.2 blank white screen in local but it has execute in php artisan serve not works in http://localhost/projectname/public/

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I've use php artisan serve command the project has loaded successfully in `laravel 5.2` but if i load **http://localhost/projectname/public/** it has shown blank white page.

How can I run my laravel 5.2 app using http://localhost/mydemo/public/ this url

Comment: Blank white page typically means: go check your server logs (apache or nginx error.log)! Also: you shouldn't be using `/public` in a laravel url usually.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up your web server so `public` directory would be set up as root directory.

For example, you're using Apache, you should do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.localhost.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public"
  <Directory "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And don't forget to restart your web server after you do this.

Comment: I've got the answer. Actually I dont have permission for laravel 5.2 bootstrap folder and storage folder. That why the http://localhost/projectname/public/ wont affect any thing. then given the permission using.          "chmod 777 -R bootstrap/"  and "chmod 777 -R storage/". Then I've got the welcome laravel page successfully.   Thanks for the above replays.

Comment: If you'll use `localhost/projectname/public`, you'll meet a lot of errors in future. You said you got the asnwer, so did you fixed it?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can choose it as best answer (check it) to thank me for my time.

Comment: chmod 777 -R bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Try running the PHP built-in sever directly from your public directory. You can check the [PHP doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) for more details, but you should be able to cd into your `mydemo/public` directory and run `php -S localhost:8000`. Then open `localhost:8000` in your browser to view the page. If you haven't made any changes to your `routes.php` file, then the default Laravel welcome page should display.

If that doesn't work, I recommend watching the episode 1 and 2 of the latest [Laravel From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch) series on Laracasts. Jeffrey walks you through all of the setup and uses 'php artisan serve' early in episode 2 to load the built-in server.